# Javascript, turn string into object attribute

Tags: javascript, object, attributes

I am wondering if it is possible to have an object with some attributes for example:

*object name: Human*

```
this.age = 8
this.name = "Steve"
```

Then have an array of strings which contain each attribute to that object such as:

```
manAttributes = ["age","name"]
```

So therefore if i wrote

```
console.log(Human.manAttributes[0])
```

The console should log '**8**' But this doesn't work, I get unexpected string.

Thanks

Comment: could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

An object is a **key:value** pair. The key and value are separated by a **:** (colon). In your case, you have separated by **=**. Change your code as below:

```
 var Human = {
     manAttributes: ["age","name"],
     age: 8
 };
 alert(Human[Human.manAttributes[0]]);  //alerts 8
```

This solution considers manAttributes as a property of Human object. If manAttributes is a separate array outside the Human object, then,

```
 var manAttributes = ["age","name"];
 var Human = {
     age: 8
 };
 alert(Human[manAttributes[0]]);  //alerts 8
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking at iterating through the properties, 
i would suggest the following approach.

```
var human = {      
  name: "Smith",
  age: "29"      
};

var manAttributes = ["age","name"];

for(var prop in manAttributes){
  if(human.hasOwnProperty(manAttributes[prop])){
    console.log(human[manAttributes[prop]]);
  }  
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kigafajo/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Object properties can be accessed through either dot notation or bracket notation (see [Mozilla's JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)).

So, this will output what you want:

```
console.log(Human[manAttributes[0]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be needing:

```
Human[manAttributes[0]]
```

The `[]` syntax being the way of accessing a property by (variable) name rather than by constant literal token.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Human(age,name) {
  this.age = age;
  this.name = name;
}
var self = new Human(8,'Steve');

var humanProperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(self);

console.log(self[humanProperties[0]])
```